# Material colorOnSurface ignored in dark theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, material-components-android

Material theme appears to ignore `colorOnSurface` in dark mode only:

values/themes.xml:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
...
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MyApp.Base">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

values-night/themes.xml:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MyApp.Base">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Testing on BOTH Samsung tablet (Android 10) AND Emulator (Android 10)

- In Light mode, `MaterialToolbar` menu renders as expected: black text on white background.
- In Dark mode, `MaterialToolbar` menu renders with **black** text on black background.

`colorOnSurface` appears completely ignored.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer. The problem is that in my base style, I defined:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"/>
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MyApp.Base">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Probably WOULD have controlled menu item color if we didn't override on the next line-->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    <!-- potentially override colorOnSurface for all subtitle 1's. WHICH components use subtitle1? You'll have to guess -->
    <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/MyApp.TextAppearance.Subtitle1</item>
</style>
<!-- Default style for menu items. Intuition be damned, the only way to learn this is by scouring the material design docs line by line -->
<style name="MyApp.TextAppearance.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Apparently, if you define `textAppearanceSubtitle1` with a color, that color will override `colorOnSurface`

To support dark mode, I had to ALSO define `textAppearanceSubtitle1` in my dark theme:

*values-night/themes.xml*:

```xml
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MyApp.Base">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/black</item>
    <!-- probably WOULD control menu color, if we hadn't defined textAppearanceSubtitle1 -->
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/white</item>
</style>
<!-- override light theme style -->
<style name="MyApp.TextAppearance.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I can't help but wonder aloud once again, just how on earth any sane developer can be expected to learn how to properly style an Android app, whose themes and styles interfere with and overlap each other and material design in an endless quagmire of guesswork and suffering.

Comment: Isn't it obvious, that by setting textAppearanceSubtitle1 in your theme, you override textAppearances for all Subtitle1 elements for the WHOLE theme??? Styling Android app, especially using MaterialComponents, is quite difficult, but this isn't the case that proves it

Comment: @d.u.a.l You're right, this isn't the case for that.  My observation was that setting `textAppearanceSubtitle1` appears to override `colorOnSurface` and that wasn't at all obvious to me.

Comment: You should refer the color from the current theme instead of color resource. That would help